# error while creating thumbnail images in javafx

Tags: javafx, fileinputstream

I created a image viewer application using javafx. I want to display all the images inside a folder as thumbnails.

> java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Java heap space

error occurs while using the below code. I also used `System.gc()` but no improvement.

```
GridPane thumbnails=new GridPane();
for (int row = 0; row < 1; row++) {
    for (int column = 0; column <= jFiles.size(); column++) {
        int newindex = column;
        String currentBackImage = FileHandler.CURRENT_DIR + "/" + jFiles.get(column).fullname;
        FileInputStream imageInput = new FileInputStream(new File(FileHandler.CURRENT_DIR + "/" + jFiles.get(column).fullname));

        String ext = currentBackImage.toLowerCase().substring(currentBackImage.lastIndexOf('.') + 1);
        if (ext.contains("tif")) {
            FileChannel channel = imageInput.getChannel();
            ByteBuffer buffer = ByteBuffer.allocate((int) channel.size());
            channel.read(buffer);
            System.gc();
            img = mainController.load(buffer.array());
            imageInput.close();

        } else {
            System.gc();
            img = new Image(imageInput);
            imageInput.close();
        }

        StackPane stack = new StackPane();                   
        ImageView view = new ImageView();                  
        view.setImage(img); 
        stack.add(view);
        thumbnails.add(stack, row, column);
        imageInput.close();

    }
}
```

Comment: How many image files are there in the folder? How much memory do you allocate to the JVM when you run your application?

Comment: when i select folder with 20 images this error occurs. I increased the heap size to -Xmx2048m

Comment: I would guess the problem comes from all the `Image`s  you're adding. Images can take up a lot of RAM, in which case allocating more memory is an obvious solution. Though I wouldn't have expected only 20 _thumbnails_ (but you appear to be loading the full-size image, not just a thumbnail) would cause a problem, not that my intuition about these things is necessarily accurate. Also, you should be using [try-with-resources](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/exceptions/tryResourceClose.html) to handle closing your `FileInputStream`.

Comment: can you explain how to load the thumbnail not the full-size image?@Slaw

Comment: Take a look at the `Image` constructors with `requestedWidth` parameters.

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34786958/creating-a-image-thumbnail-in-javafx?rq=1

Comment: thanks a lot @fabian I used Image constructor to display the image thumbnails and it works fine thanks a lot :)